# Detect if Cordova plugin exists

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

Is there a way to tell if a specific Cordova plugin is available to be called in Cordova 2.5.0? `Cordova.exec` takes in a `successFunction` and a `failFunction` but the `failFunction` is only called if the native code executes. Is there a way to receive an error or callback if the receiving function doesn't exist? I'm looking for a solution that works with a remove URL loaded into WebView

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/guide_plugin-development_ios_index.md.html

Comment: I know you're trying to detect if it exists, but can you not use a try catch and sort of achieve the same? Call the plugin in the try, if the plugin doesn't exist then the code in the catch will be executed.

Comment: for this you need to develop another plugin that check existence of another plugins , you just need to call smth like PluginChecker and see if your requested plugin exist or not

Comment: wich os you need this? ios or android?

Comment: Ideally, I'd like it to work on both, but iOS is the priority. Basically, I have different versions of an iOS client connecting to the same webpage with phonegap running on it. If a plugin is detected, I want to enable a feature on the website. If an older version of the client doesn't have the plugin, I want the feature to be deactivated.

Comment: @AndrewLively, I can't get the try/catch to work. A 404 is generated when the cordova JS code tries to execute the plugin, but an exception isn't thrown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do a setTimeout for 100 ms before trying to access the plugin, and on success/failure of the plugin cancel the timeout. if the timeout triggers - the plugin is not installed.

Answer (score 14):

For a quite simpler (and cleaner) solution, you can also use this method :

```
var plugins = cordova.require("cordova/plugin_list").metadata;
```

You'll get an object looking like that :

```
{
    'cordova-plugin-network-information': "1.0.0",
    'cordova-plugin-whitelist': "1.0.0"
}
```

As any normal variable, you can then check if it's defined :

```
if (typeof plugins['cordova-plugin-whitelist'] === "undefined")
{
    // This plugin is missing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't completely safe, but you should be able to read config.xml and search for the plugin configuration to see if the plug is registered:

```
var myPluginName = "MyPluginName";
var myPluginExists = false;
$.ajax(
    {
        url: "../config.xml",
        success: 
            function(configXML)
            {
                myPluginExists = (configXML.indexOf(myPluginName) > 0);
            },
        dataType: "text"
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I specified this earlier, but I'm looking for something that would work when the JS is running on a remote server and doesn't have access to the files in the project.

Comment: No, you specified that. I just didn't appreciate what you were getting at. I assumed that you were talking about the JS on the device because if the JS is on the server, you won't have access to cordova.exec anyway.